# Script option taking wildcards

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, wildcard

Is it acceptable to have an option that takes wildcards (e.g. for files)

For instance, I could hove a bash script that is called as follows

```
rando -s /angio/repo/A*
```

Have coded an argument parsing as follows, but need some assistance on how to robustly parse options with wildcards (such as `-s`).

```
rando ()
{
    local  incl=()  fls=()
    
    IFSPREV="$IFS"  # Save IFS (splits on whitespace)
    IFS="="         # Split "="
    set -- $*
    IFS="$IFSPREV"  # Set original IFS
   
    local  iarg=0  narg="$#"
    
    while (( narg > 0 )); do  
        opt="$1"
        iarg=$(( iarg + 1 ))
    
        case $opt in
            ("-s"|"--src"|"--source")  src=$( "$2" )  ; shift 2 ;;
            ("-d"|"--dst"|"--destin")  dst="$2"  ; shift 2 ;;
            #............................................................
            ("--")  shift 1 ; break ;;
            ("-"*)  printf '%s\n' "Unknown option: $1" ; shift 1 ;;
            (*) fls+=( "$2" ) ; shift 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    
    printf '%s\n' "src: $src"
    return
}
```

Comment: The `find` command is doing exactly this for its value of the `-name` and `-iname` option, but of course this would not work in the way you sketched it here: `bash` will expand the pattern and your script would not see any wild card. If you want _mybaschscript_ to get the wildcard  pattern, you have to invoke it as `mybashscript -s '/angio/repo/A*'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly acceptable. In most situations the wild card will have already been expanded before being passed into your script as one or more arguments (see here for bash docs on [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)). So you won't even know that a wild card was used.

The one caveat is when no file name matches the pattern, from the docs:

> If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option *nullglob* is disabled, the word is left unchanged

This means that if there are no files in `/angio/repo` that start with `A`, the only argument that will be passed in the literal pattern `/angio/repo/A*`. In most cases this won't be too much of an issue since you can simply check if there are multiple arguments passed, and if only 1 was given check if it exists:

```sh
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "no files that matched the pattern '$1' exist..."
    exit 1
fi

# do something to each file
for path in "$@"; do
    echo "$path matched the pattern"
done
```

However, you shouldn't write your scripts assuming that the user is going to either use or not use wild cards. In your case just make sure that your script is able to properly handle being passed one or more paths being given to it and you should be fine.

Comment: That's the difficult part.  Do you know of any bash examples that handle such option (i.e with more than one value associated with some option)?

Comment: You'll see it pretty commonly, commands like `rm` will let you specify multiple commands to remove at one time. Typically you just need to loop over the values, and do whatever operations you want to each file

Comment: @Angio I modified the snippet I provided to be a bit more clear about how to loop over the different paths